# How to withdraw liquid out of a injector in a pressurized autoclave?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure

I am using a hand spindle press to inject liquid into a pressurized autoclave through a stainless steel pipe. I was wondering is there any possible way to retrieve all of the remaining liquid out of the pipe without depressurizing the autoclave?

Also, I cannot use the hand spindle press to withdraw the remaining liquid. It would be nice if you can suggest to me some of literature about this problem.

Comment: can you provide a sketch with the principal dimensions of your setup? esppecially pipe lengths and diameters. What's the liquid? Is some dilution with water or so acceptable? What's the puropose if the withdrawal, reuse or something else?

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not have the sketch. The pipe is standing upward with 250m in length and 6mm in diameter. Since i will increase the autoclave's temperature after injecting TMOS or TEOS liquid, the remaing liquid in the pipe might change into solid  which will block the whole pipe system if i don't take them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an isolation valve at the autoclave and a vent valve there as well on the supply side.

Shut the isolation valve and open the vent and the liquid could gravity drain.  You could then use the vent during fill to avoid injecting air into the autoclave.  Leve the vent open until liquid comes out of it, shut the vent, open the isolation and begin injection.

Comment: I had a more complicated idea with a three way ball valve and possible an extra water connection to flush (4 bar off the tap should be enough) but I think this is good an solves the OP problem. AFAIK TMOS is applied with organic solvents, OP should check for safety/vapors.